# Cannot POST more than one value with AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I stucked on one thing. I have a 2 grid inside checkboxes. When I selected that checkboxes I want to POST that row data values like array or List. Actually when i send one list item it's posting without error but when i get more than one item it couldn't post values.

Example of my grid 
[image: Example of my grid]

Here my ajax request and how to select row values function

```
 var grid = $("#InvoceGrid").data('kendoGrid');
var sel = $("input:checked", grid.tbody).closest("tr");
var items = [];
$.each(sel, function (idx, row) {
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    items.push(item);
});

var grid1 = $("#DeliveryGrid").data('kendoGrid');
var sel1 = $("input:checked", grid1.tbody).closest("tr");
var items1 = [];
$.each(sel1, function (idx, row) {
    var item1 = grid1.dataItem(row);
    items1.push(item1);
});

$.ajax({
    url: '../HeadOffice/CreateInvoice',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'items': items, 'items1': items1, 'refnum': refnum }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == "0") {
            $("#lblMessageInvoice").text("Invoices have been created.")
            var del = $("#InvoiceOKWindow").data("kendoWindow");
            del.center().open();
            var del1 = $("#InvoiceDetail").data("kendoWindow");
            del1.center().close();
            $("#grdDlvInv").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        }
        else {
            $("#lblMessageInvoice").text("Problem occured. Please try again later.")
            var del = $("#InvoiceOKWindow").data("kendoWindow");
            del.center().open();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

This is my C# part

```
[HttpPost]
    public string CreateInvoice(List<Pm_I_GecisTo_Result> items, List<Pm_I_GecisFrom_Result> items1, string refnum)
    {
        try
        {
            if (items != null && items1 != null)
            {
                //do Something
            }
            else
            {
                Log.append("Items not selected", 50);
                return "-1";
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.append("Exception in Create Invoice action of HeadOfficeController " + ex.ToString(), 50);
            return "-1";
        }
    }
```

But when i send just one row it works but when i try to send more than one value it post null and create problem

How can i solve this? Do you have any idea?

**EDIT**

I forgot to  say but this way is working on localy but when i update server is not working proper.

Comment: try removing tradional:true

Comment: Is this WebAPI? If it's WebAPI you cannot have multiple params binding on your `CreateInvoice` only 1, use `[FromBody]` attribute. Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @12seconds no this is not WebAPI this is MVC Web application

Comment: @johnny5 no not working :(

Comment: You're going to just have so many issues with this.  Instead, create a single model that encapsulates all of this and bind according, [including your lists](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: Paste your controller code in (don't use images...)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $.ajax({
                url: '../HeadOffice/CreateInvoice',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                data: { items: items, items1: items1 }

                success: function (msg) {
                   //add codes
                },
                error: function () {
                    location.reload();
                }

            });
```

try to call controller by this method :)

Comment: what about stringfy?? @MAC